# How do I spawn Enderdragons in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the quickest way to spawn [Enderdragons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon) in Minecraft?

Is there an easy single-player mod? Would it be easier to do it somehow with Bukkit?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to include a screenshot or a better description of the mob you are referring to. I, for one, haven't a clue what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-110-single-player-commands-v311-official-download/), You get about a hundred useful mods in one. Once installed, just type

> spawn [63](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without mods?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it with MCEdit by placing a spawner and changing the id appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason why [Enderdragons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon) spawn only in the End. If you made one spawn in the overworld, it would most likely wreak havoc on your structures and terrorize your world until you kill it, similar to the newly added [Wither](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither). However, if you really want to spawn it, install [Single Player Commands](http://bit.ly/spcmod) and type `/spawn enderdragon`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through the  [Mob Spawner mod](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_spawner) .  You have to have the latest beta version to do it though.

Or [Watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzd31yR_0gs) I have found for it. [its rather slow, but everything is there]  The author provides that mod in the notes and the dragons are located in *The End* area.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Minecraft, this can be done without any mods using a `/summon` command.

```
/summon ender_dragon
```

However, an ender dragon summoned using commands won't actually do anything unless given a `DragonPhase` NBT tag, see [How do I successfully summon the Ender Dragon using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/348463/185203).

Answer (score 0):

There is a mod that makes it easy to spawn Enderdragons called 'Too Many Items'. It has an Enderdragon spawner.

Answer (score 0):

Without mods, you can travel to [The End,](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End) which is guaranteed to have one Enderdragon (until you kill it).