# How do I successfully summon the Ender Dragon using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Whenever I summon the Ender Dragon with the `/summon` command in chat or in a command block, it doesn't move and is untouchable. The only effect that occurs is that it lags out my (garbage) Windows 8 PC.

This doesn't happen in The End. This glitch appears with or without mods, on singleplayer, multiplayer and realms worlds.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Reopen reason: It's clear what the question is about. Just try it: `/summon ender_dragon`. That's enough to observe that behaviour.

Comment: Here's the report: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-95601

Comment: @FabianRöling might be worth editing that into the question for clarity

Comment: @Malco What? It's already in there: "Whenever I summon the Ender Dragon […], it doesn't move"

Comment: @FabianRöling that is to say, editing the actual command in. The command might be obvious to people who are familiar with it, but on the surface this question looks like it is missing information (which might have been why it was attracting unclear close votes).

Comment: @Malco putting the command in is probably a good idea although not really necessary in this particular case. But voting to close a question, because one doesn't know the topic is questionable. Unclear votes should be cast for lack of content, not for people who are not familiar with the topic of the question.

Comment: @dly it would be nice if people only voted like that, but sometimes people aren't aware of what they don't know, and other times they are just cruising through the review queue.

Answer (score 6):

according to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon), you need to add a "Dragon Phase" NBT tag to him for him to work. to quote;

> The `/summon ender_dragon` command, by default, summons a harmless ender dragon that hovers in place. Setting the DragonPhase tag (for instance by issuing `/summon ender_dragon ~ ~ ~ {DragonPhase:0}`) will create a normal ender dragon, but it will have no health bar since the bar is managed by the End's dragon fight status rather than by the dragon entity itself. If spawned away from the center of the map (X:0, Z:0), the dragon will first fly to the center before resuming normal behavior (see #Behavior).