# Summoned Ender dragon stuck in perpetual movement

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I spawned an Ender dragon using the `/summon` command into the Overworld, expecting it to fly around and destroy everything in a 10 mile radius.

Instead, the Ender dragon spun around on the spot right after being summoned and kept spinning around, flying in bigger and bigger circles, after which it got stuck flying around in a circle with a radius of about 10 blocks (as shown in picture). I then watched the dragon not move out of that circle for another 5 minutes.

[image: Dragon with red circle around it.]

I tried summoning the dragon in the End too, and got the same result. However, respawning the dragon through End crystals resulted in a normal behaving dragon.

Is this intended? Can I somehow get a summoned dragon to behave "normally"?

I am playing on 1.19.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I successfully summon the Ender Dragon using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348463/how-do-i-successfully-summon-the-ender-dragon-using-commands)

Comment: @pppery didn't find that when searching. Thanks so much!